# I would like to number the figure in my presentation in LaTeX

Tags: beamer, number

I need to number the figure in my presentation, but I do not know why the figure appears without the number.  I try what I could find on the Internet, but I still do not get the number. Instead of Figure, I would *like* Figure1 ecc.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[t,9pt,pdftex]{beamer}
\usetheme{tb}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[horizontal]
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{figure}}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-1.5em}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{orange}$\blacktriangleright$}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=7 cm\textwidth]{var.png}
    \caption{VAR Analysis figure adapted from \text{Lütkepohl}.}
  \label{fig: VAR Analysis figure }
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a semantic error in `\includegraphics[width=7 cm\textwidth]{var.png}`. It should (probably) be `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{var.png}`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's the purpose of `\text{Lütkepohl}`? Why not just write `Lütkepohl`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]` to get numbered captions.

Some other comments:

- Don't use `pdftex` as class option. In the best case it is not necessary, because latex can automatically figure out how you are compiling your document, worst case it will force latex to use the wrong graphic drivers etc.
- Don't use `\usepackage{ucs}` and the `utf8x` option for inputenc. Both of them aren't necessary and can cause problems depending on which hyperref version you have installed.
- `\usepackage{graphicx}` is not necessary, beamer loads it for you
- `\usepackage{multicol}`: beamer has its own column mechanism, better use this instead of multicol
- instead of hardcoding the item colour, I suggest to use the appropriate beamer templates:

  ```
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange}
  ```
- beamer does not have a floating mechanism, it makes no sense to specify floating specifier like `[h]`
- beamer figures are centred by default, no need for `\centering`
- the syntax `width=7 cm\textwidth` isn't valid. Use either `7cm` or `\textwidth`, but not some combination of both
- `var.png` -> better use just the file name without file type. If you have the same figure in different formats, latex will automatically be able to choose the format best suited for the engine you use.
- Like @Mico already remarked, `\text{Lütkepohl}` makes not a lot of sense, in particular not outside of math mode
- `\label{fig: VAR Analysis figure }`: Do yourself a favour and don't use spaces in labels
- Don't abuse `\\` for line breaks. In your screenshot, you are using if after the figure, it will cause an error there.

---

```
\documentclass[t,9pt]{beamer}
%\usetheme{tb}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-1.5em}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{VAR Analysis figure adapted from Lütkepohl.}
    \label{fig: VAR Analysis figure }  
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]